A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'. Could not initialize class com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.decorator.AndroidPluginDs
I am building the app using flutter. I was getting warning everytime I build the app, so I followed Flutter migration from official docs and got this error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\flutter\intern\SOS42-tester\android\build.gradle' line: 13

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Build completed with 1 failures.
   > Could not initialize class com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.decorator.AndroidPluginDslDecoratorKt


BUILD FAILED in 1s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I am attaching build.gradle and settings.gradle files here:
android/build.gradle file:
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

android/settings.gradle file:
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }()

    includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0" apply false
    id "com.android.application" version "7.2.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.7.20" apply false
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.4.0" apply false
    id "com.google.firebase.crashlytics" version "2.9.9" apply false
    id("com.google.firebase.firebase-perf") version "1.4.2" apply false
}

include ":app"

android/app/build.gradle file:
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "com.google.firebase.crashlytics"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id "com.google.gms.google-services"
    id "com.google.firebase.firebase-perf"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 34
    ndkVersion "25.1.8937393"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID
        //(https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "club.edventure.sos42"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-
        //the-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']):null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release { 
           ndk{
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86_64'
           }
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }

}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.3.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-playintegrity'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:19.0.7'
}

